# Is there a way to query a std::locale for a list of all facets currently installed?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, locale

I am familiar with the use of std::has_facet(loc) to determine whether a specific facet has been loaded into a locale.

```
if ( ! std::has_facet<custom_facet_t>(std::cout.getloc()) ) {
   /* load facet in to locale */
}
```

Is there a way to get a list of all facets currently loaded? 
Given the nature of locales, I am fairly certain that it would violate all types of rules... but I had to ask  :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe (as you've surmised) that the answer is no. The `locale` class supports construction, assignment, name retrieval, comparison (or equality and inequality only), and function-invocation. The only (required) free functions are `use_facet` and `has_facet`, along with the `is*` and `to*` convenience interfaces.

There's simply nothing there that looks like it can support enumeration/traversal/iteration.